# Passing variable data using sessions in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
class PaymentGatewayController1 extends Controller
{
public function getPaymentGatewayResponse(Request $request)
{
    $input = request()->input();

    Session::put(['email' => $input['email']]);
    Session::save();
return view('elements.blocks.iframe2',  ['response' => $input]);
}
}
```

Now I need this session value to another controller

```
class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $input = request()->all();
    $data = $request->session()->get('email');
    dd($data);
}
}
```

it returns null value

Laravel Version 5.8

Comment: try to use the helper function instead of the facade `session(['email' => $input['email']])` antoher thing when you retrieve it just write `session('email')` at the end check your `$input` value before save it in your session

Comment: Change `Session::put(['email' => $input['email']]);` to `Session::put(['email' => $request->email]);`

Answer (score 0):

Change your first controllert to this

```
class PaymentGatewayController1 extends Controller
{
    public function getPaymentGatewayResponse(Request $request){
        $input = request()->input();
        Session::put(['email' => $request->email]);
        Session::save();
        return view('elements.blocks.iframe2',  ['response' => $input]);
    }
}
```

And in retrieving controller use this

```
class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request){
        $input = request()->all();
        $data = Session::get('email);
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to flush the session to avoid the security loopholes after the completion of flow

Comment: @JagadeeshChandra try dd($request->email) in your first controller and let me know the result

Comment: `Session::put(['email' => $request->email]);`
        `Session::save();`
     `$data = Session::get('email');`
       `dd($data);` I get the session value here `par@aol.com`

Comment: I tested this with other controllers, its working fine. However, it's not working for the above controllers.

Comment: @JagadeeshChandra Can you confirm once that you are not flushing the session anywhere in this controller

Comment: I figured out the issue, I'm trying to store the response from payment gateway in sessions and its not happening. Session getting destroyed after Payment gateway redirecting to success callback url.

Comment: @JagadeeshChandra You can store in cache then or else create a temp table and store there

Comment: Storing data at cache is not changing it is application-based, is there any way we can use sessions